# Relocating a node JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm creating a maze game where there will be multiple 'chasers' following  a player round a maze, to do this I need to relocate the chasers however i've ran into an issue using .relocate() it only moves it once ,I understand it does this because it shifts the whole coordinates axis itself rather than just the nodes coordinates.

I cannot use chaser.setCentreX() unfortunately to move it  as I will be dynamically creating the nodes and will all have the same name 'chaser' hence why I am using getChildren() to get the coordinates. To differentiate between the multiple chasers I will use .setId() .getId() so that I can access the LayoutBounds of a specific node. For example if there were three chasers the first one would be called 'chaser' with and Id of 1 then the next with and Id of 2 etc..

Is there an alternative way of relocating a node without having this issue? , the code below demonstrates the problem.

```
 package sample;

 import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
 import javafx.animation.Timeline;
 import javafx.application.Application;
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.EventHandler;
 import javafx.scene.Scene;
 import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
 import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
 import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Pane pane=new Pane();
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 600));
    primaryStage.show();

    Circle chaser=new Circle();
    chaser.setRadius(12);
    chaser.setCenterX(100);
    chaser.setCenterY(50);
    chaser.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
    pane.getChildren().add(chaser);

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(30), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) { 
            System.out.println("running");
            pane.getChildren().get(0).relocate(chaser.getCenterX()+400,chaser.getCenterY());



        }
    }));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: .setTranslate doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `relocate` does is assign the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties. Those are completely independent from `centerX` and `centerY`. Since the latter properties are never updated, the target location remains constant regardless of how often you execute `relocate(chaser.getCenterX()+400,chaser.getCenterY());` on `chaser`.

To see updates, you need to refer to an value that is updated when updating the location, e.g.

```
chaser.relocate(chaser.getLayoutX() + 400, chaser.getLayoutY());
```

or

```
chaser.setCenterX(chaser.getCenterX() + 400);
// chaser.setCenterY(chaser.getCenterY());
```

or

```
chaser.setTranslateX(chaser.getTranslateX() + 400);
// chaser.setTranslateY(chaser.getTranslateY());
```

---

As for using ids: That seems completely unnecessary. You could keep track of the chasers without using the CSS id by simply storing them in a suitable data structure. If those are the only children of the parent, you don't even need an extra datastructure, since every chaser would be stored in the children list in that case...

Comment: Just note that the chaser will pretty much vanish immediately, since you're moving the node by 400 px every 30 ms.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , I tried your 3rd code example and it works , moves the circle . However when I try to get the new centre coordinate it doesnt change? even though its moving

Comment: I tried implementing the 2nd example and used your idea of using a data structure to store the chasers and that works perfectly . Thanks for your help!

Comment: The position the circle is rendered at is determined by a combination of all those properties. Updating one of the other properties has no effect the other ones. If you use multiple of those you need to take all those that are modified into consideration when determining the position the circle is rendered at.